# JqueryUI Autocomplete works perfect in JSFiddle but not on the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

Hi I have worked on it for couple of hours, but still could not figure it out.

The code works perfect on JSFiddle, but not on my site.

This is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/sbAR6/16/

And also I have added the link for Jquery and JqueryUI.

```
<script src="/media/js/jquery-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/media/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/media/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/media//css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The links was download from JQuery website and upload on my site, and I could open them in the Inspect Element of Chrome, they all the same with the original ones.

But the autocomplete just does not work at all, nothing appears when I was typing in, and also Firebug does not return any error on the site.

and also I have tried add `$( document ).ready(function() { .. });` before the javascript code, but it still does not work

Could anyone helps me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

jsFiddle does load it on window.load default

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // your code
});
```

---

[image]

Comment: Hi I added the $( document ).ready() before my code but still not working, sry I did not mention that in the question

Answer (score 1):

try removing one of the 2 / symbols between media and css in your last link

```
<link href="/media/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: you also appear to be missing a script reference to bootstrap.js

Comment: I did not use any javascript in bootstrap, so I did not reference to bootstrap.js